# What is the name of the maths topic/subtopic containing this Propositional Logic expression p1, p2,...p3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, notation

**TLDR:**
I'm new to Discrete Mathematics and Calculus, this is a beginner question. What is the name of the maths topic which contains an expression I will describe as the variable n above a large logical AND symbol with a variable assignment below the AND symbol such as i=1 or j=i+1. My guess is this a mix of calculus and propositional logic however I can't find this expression online looking though calculus and propositional logic examples like it is in my Discrete Mathematics book. It's in the topic Propositional Logic however there is not sufficient explanation in this topic for me to understand the expression. Please state the name of a topic containing an explanation of an expression in this format.

**The long version:**
In the following proposition, n is the nth value of p, however I don't know what i represents:

### n-1

### ^

### i=1

> An example is, if p1, p2,...,pn are n propositions, explain why

```
n-1 
^
i=1

n 
^ 
j=i+1

(!pi V !pj)
```

> is true if and only if at most one of p1, p2,....,pn is true.

The answer is that only one true truth value for p(n) makes the expression true because:

> !True OR !True
> OR !True

is false, and

> !True OR !True
> OR !False

is true, because !False is true making the entire expression true.

However I don't have a plain english explanation for what i and j represent. n is the nth value of p but what is the relationship between n, i and j when translated to propositional logic.

I have made some progress in understanding i and j when working out the n-Queens puzzle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle, i and j together with k can relate to the rows, columns and diagonals to ensure chess queens are distributed in non-attack mode. However without understanding the basics it makes it difficult to extrapolate these more complex examples to understand the topic.

My book has suggested that some questions may involve differential or integral calculus however I have not found this style of expression I described in these topics or in propositional calculus.

**What I need:**
Propositional logic is mostly written in the format `!(p ^ q) === !p V !q` However when it's written in the stacked format of n, followed by AND followed by i=1 I don't understand it. I'm looking for the name of this stacked expression which as far as I'm aware is not just called propositional logic.

**Edit:**
I thought this was resolved for me except I don't understand the calculation on this answer [How do I interpret \bigwedge notation in discrete math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020856/how-do-i-interpret-bigwedge-notation-in-discrete-math) for n=4.

If the question is:

$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1} \bigwedge_{j=i+1}^n (\neg p_i \vee \neg p_j)$$

for n=4, the answer is:

$$\begin{align*}
(\neg p_1\lor\neg p_2)\land(\neg p_1\lor\neg p_3)\land(\neg p_1\lor\neg p_4)\\
\land(\neg p_2\lor\neg p_3)\land(\neg p_2\lor\neg p_4)\land(\neg p_3\lor\neg p_4)\,.
\end{align*}$$

For the first half of the n=1 iteration, i=1 and j=i+1 which is j=2, this gives:
$$\begin{align*}
(\neg p_1\lor\neg p_2)\end{align*}$$

After the first AND symbol I get lost, if pi is p1 and j is j=i+1 then this is j=1+1 which is j=2. Why is pj shown as p3? Are we already iterating to n=2 and i=2 at this point?

I'm not sure if iterating by n means that i becomes the number n each iteration. Also not sure if n-1 means that we only iterate up to 3 which is 4-1, which is 0, 1, 2, 3 giving a total or 4 iterations, or if n-1 means we subtract 1 from n each iteration.

If I guess that when n=2 and i=2 then this explains p3 as being j=i+1 which is j=2+1 which is j=3, giving p3. But when pj is shown as p3, pi is still shown as p1 which means i=2 can't be correct, unless the n-1 has something to do with it. As in n=2, i=n, i=2, n-1 is 2-1 so pi is p1. I'm not picking up how this big wedge expression is meant to be calculated. I'm pretty sure the way I described it is totally wrong but like the other person asking said, there is no context or info about this big wedge expression it's just assumed knowledge.

Can someone please step through the n=4 answer and how we arrive at each compound proposition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the same way as a summation symbol $\Sigma$ is often used with the range of summation indicated below it and above it, the large "and" symbol is used in your case. Also it uses a double "and", similar to a double summation with ranges for each sum, where the inside range may depend on the outside range.

Comment: Maybe [generalized conjunction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020856/how-do-i-interpret-bigwedge-notation-in-discrete-math): $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}  p_i $. And similar for disjunction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you this is what I was looking for. This resolves my question.

Comment: And it is *propositional calculus*; we may simply define it inductively, starting from $\bigwedge_1^2 p_i = p_1 \land p_2$.

Comment: When there are only two numbers ranging from 1 to 2 it's easy to see how we get p1 ^ p2 however when we iterate by n I'm just not picking up why we get compound propositions like p1 ^ p3 or p1 ^ p4 in my edit.

Comment: I searched for generalized conjunction and propositional calculus however didn't come across the explanation for calculations using the bigwedge. I eventually worked it out and provided an explanation as an answer but this got deleted. So I will just make the comment that the bigwedge is analogous to nested for loops in programming where j is nested in i.